# Is there any way to use one thumb as the source of another?

Tags: paperclip

I need paperclip to create pictures for iphone4 and iphone5. iphone4 is a bit smaller, so my declaration looks looks like this:

```
has_attached_file :picture, styles: {
  iphone5: '640×1136>',
  iphone4: '640×960#'
}, default_url: :get_default_url
```

The idea behind this was, I want the iphone4 thumb just exactly like the iphone5 one, but crop it after scaling, but this doesnt work, because the original gets cropped.

So how can I solve this? This seems such a common problem for me, I also think I have seen something like declaring the iphone4 input should be the iphone5 thumb and not the original, but I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it now with just two sizes with the uploaded image forced to have the same dimensions as the iphone 5. The declaration of the attachment looks like this:

```
has_attached_file :profile_photo, styles: {
  iphone5: '640×1136>',
  iphone4: '',
}, convert_options: {iphone4: "-gravity south -thumbnail 640x960^ -extent 640x960"},
        default_url: :set_default_url_for_profile_photo
```